# WebhookClient.add() is not working anymore

Tags: node.js, webhooks, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I am using DialogFlow's inline editor. In webhook, I send the speech response from google assistant to the user via the `WebhookClient.add()` API. But it doesnt seem to be working now. I know that the V2 APIs have been launched and its official now. I thought i was using the V2 API. Looks like its not. Please tell me the alternative for `WebhookClient.add()`. I tried using `conv` but its not working either. Here's how i used it:

```
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({request, response});
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));
  const conv = agent.conv();

  function welcome(agent) {
    agent.add('Welcome to MY AGENT');//This and the next line are not sending speech output.Earlier it was working fine
    agent.add('This is the Webhook');
    conv.ask('Welcome to My agent');
    conv.ask('This is the Webhook!');
  }
let intentMap = new Map(); // Map functions to Dialogflow intent names
intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
}
```

Please help me what's wrong with this.
UPDATE:Added intent mapping

Comment: Can you elaborate on "it doesn't seem to be working now"? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors . I checked the logs . Even the samples given by Dialog flow(temperature converter) is not working .

Comment: Your code snippet is pretty confusing. I'm not sure why you're using both `agent.add` and `conv.ask` as you only should be using one or the other I think.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, you're trying to make certain intents include a response via fulfillment so you'll need to make sure you enable the toggle `Enable webhook call for this intent` for all the intents where you'd like to include the agent.add() method.
Also, you should only use conv for Actions on Google-specific features.

```
'use strict';

 const functions = require('firebase-functions');
 const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

 process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

 exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

  function welcome (agent) {
    agent.add(`Hey buddy, welcome to my agent!`);
  }

  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```